# Java: How to dynamically add classes to the interface class in java

Tags: java, gradle, junit, e2e-testing

I am pretty new to java, still a lot learn. I have created an interface class called FailedTest. After all of the tests run, I would like to add the failed tests classes to the FailedTest interface class. Once I have all of the failed tests, I would like to create a gradle task to run all of the failed tests again. I am using Junit, Intellij and Gradle.

FailedTest interface class in categories package:------

```
package myPackage.categories;

public interface FailedTests {
}
```

TestExecutionListener in listeners:----------

```
@Category(FailedTests.class)

public void afterTestExecution(TestContext testContext) {

  if (testContext.getTestException() != null) {

  // i would like to add failed tests to the FailedTest interface class here

   FailedTests = testContext.getTestClass();

  }
}
```

In build.gradle I would like create following task:----------

```
task testFailedTests(type: Test) {ext.getTestMethodsFromStorage = { ->

  //return a string array of the test classes/methods from the file:FailedTest 
  }

  useJUnit {

    include getTestMethodsFromStorage()

  }
}
```

I would appreciate any help or feedback. Thank you!

Comment: Could either of these help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8295100/3124333 https://stackoverflow.com/q/48815890/3124333

Comment: Great, I will check them out.